# URL Rewrite not displaying css ,img and js files

Tags: .htaccess

My .htaccess file looks as below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)?$ /fm/page_new?location=$1&
r_id=$2&name=$3 [L]
```

Now, when i land on page_new (`URL:http://localhost/fm/delhi/25/moods`) via above rewrite then none of my css,js and img files are getting applied to page.

I googled it how to do it and i got below code

```
 # Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
 RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     
 \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

This also does not accomplish the goal as above rule allows `.php`  access and i want to restrict same. However with above rewrite, css and js and img files also not getting applied.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because your links are relative URLS (looks like `<img src="something.png">` vs `<img src="/full/path/something.png">`). So either change your links to absolute URLs or add a relative URI base to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/fm/" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... this saved my hell lots of time :)  .. i actually dint want to change URLs to absolute... can u let me know if this tag is supported by all browsers?

Comment: @ Jon Lin ... When i rewrite URL as `http://www.example.com/delhi1/23/moods` then `<base href="/" />` is not working and again css, js and img files distorted :(